# Проблемы с использованием параметра -Pin в функции New-SelfSignedCertificate

Tags: powershell, сертификат, цифровая-подпись

Мне нужно создать сертификат, защищённый паролем, с помощью средств Powershell. Я  использую функцию таким образом:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "123456" -AsPlainText -Force
$certif = New-SelfSignedCertificate `
  -Type Custom `
  -KeySpec Signature `
  -KeyUsageProperty Sign `
  -KeyUsage DigitalSignature `
  -KeyExportPolicy Exportable `
  -KeyLength 2048 `
  -HashAlgorithm sha256 `
  -Subject "CN=Иван Иванов,C=RU,L=Челябинск,O=Интерсвязь,E=apr@intersvyaz.net" `
  -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" `
  -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(5) `
  -FriendlyName "Внутренний ЭДО Интерсвязь"`
  -Pin $password
```

Но функция возвращает вот такую ошибку:

```
    New-SelfSignedCertificate : CertEnroll::CX509Enrollment::_CreateRequest: Указан
 неправильный тип. 0x8009000a (-2146893814 NTE_BAD_TYPE)
строка:1 знак:11
+ $certif = New-SelfSignedCertificate `
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-SelfSignedCertificate], E 
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Exception,Microsoft.CertificateServices.C 
   ommands.NewSelfSignedCertificateCommand
```

Сертификат без -Pin прекрасно создаётся, но подписываться этим сертификатом могут все, кто имеет к нему доступ. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы перед подписанием документа этим сертификатом, сервис запрашивал пароль. Подозреваю, что для этого и существует параметр -Pin.

Мой вопрос вот в чём: Правильно ли я использую этот параметр? Существуют ли другие способы защитить сертификат паролем, если да, то как я могу этого добиться?

Comment: Так как вы создали сертификат в персональном хранилище, то вам достаточно ограничить доступ к вашей учетной записи. Чтобы в неё логинились только те люди, которым это разрешено. Кроме того, у команды есть ключ `-KeyProtection`, он  по умолчанию стоит None, то есть использовать можно без ограничений. Поставьте ` -KeyProtection "ProtectHigh"`. Откроется специальное окошечко, в котором нужно будет указать пароль.

Comment: @PakUla , благодарю, это именно то, что мне было нужно!